# String .replace() does not work with '$' symbol

Tags: javascript

So, I cannot figure out what is wrong? I know that `.replace()` returns a new string, without mutable existing. It's really ridiculous, but I'm stuck on this. I need to replace '$' on '2', but it just concat string, not replace the value...

```js
var answer_form = '$0';

var question_num = 2;
answer_form = answer_form.replace(/$/g, question_num); 

console.log(answer_form);
```

Comment: answer_form = answer_form.replace(/\$/g, question_num);

Comment: Good find, @Nina.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$` in regex means the end of a string. Use `"` if you do not want to use regular expressions or escape the character like this: `\$`.

```js
var answer_form = '$0';

var question_num = 2;
answer_form = answer_form.replace(/\$/g, question_num); 

console.log(answer_form);
```

Comment: Thank you! I just forgot this... Oh

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider marking this as the answer to your question so other users might find this as well.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var answer_form = '$0';

var question_num = 2;
answer_form = answer_form.replace(/[$]/g, question_num); 

console.log(answer_form);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Always say *what* you did, *why*, and *how* it works.

Answer (score -1):

The first argument in `String.replace` method can be a regular expression or a `String`.

In your example, you are using regular expression, in which `$` has a special meaning, which matches end of string. To match a literal `$`, you will have to escape using `\`, as in the following example -

`answer_form = answer_form.replace(/\$/g, question_num);`